# Android pubnub google map marker not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, pubnub

I am developing an application using google map and pubnub to show markers. I have a fragment which contains map fragment. Launching app will show map fragment and subscribe to pubnub channel. While receiving message from pubnub I am showing markers on map, for first time the map shows markers. But when I replace the fragment with the same fragment. Again the pubnub channel is subscribe and getting message, but the marker is not displaying. The following is my code.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
             mPubnub.subscribe(channel, new Callback() {
                    . . .
                    . . .

                    @Override
                    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                       if (mMap != null) {
                          if (message instanceof JSONArray) {

                          } else if (message instanceof JSONObject) {
                             updateMarker(message);
                          } else if (message instanceof String) {

                       }
            }
                    }
             });
        }
    }
```

Adding or updating marker

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("title").position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

Unsubscribing pubnub

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPubnub.unsubscribe(channel);
}
```

Comment: "Again the pubnub channel is subscribe and getting message, but the marker is not displaying." It seems PubNub is working fine here. Looks like this is a job for an Android map ninja, but we'll monitor in case there is any PubNub aspects that need to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the responce @CraigConover.

Comment: It seems unsubscribe in not working. I am receiving messages even after unsubscribing from channel.

Comment: Might have something to do with the way you are using Fragments with PubNub. Seen some wonkiness with them before. Try to reproduce using the PubNub SDK debug jar and send us the log file and the full project sources zipped to support@pubnub.com. Include all details and the link to this SO thread, and I'll have our Android engineers look into it. Cheers, Craig